# Get the first matching value from a Map

Tags: apex

I have a map as below

```
Map<Integer, Boolean> coursesMap = new Map<Integer, Boolean>();

coursesMap.put(24658, false);
coursesMap.put(11432, false);
coursesMap.put(121501,true);
coursesMap.put(121502,true);
```

I would like to get the first occurence of the map element whose value is "`true`".

In the above example that would be the key "121501"

Can someone tell me how to do this ?

Comment: What do you mean by first?  A map is unordered, so the order isn't guaranteed

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, this is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). As Nick mentioned, maps have no concept of order, so your question doesn't make sense as written. You've chosen a solution (the "Y" in the X-Y Problem) instead of telling us about the "X", the overall problem you're trying to solve. Focus on the bigger picture here and provide plenty of details about it. From there, people can guide you to a more appropriate (and more possible) solution.

Comment: Please edit your question with more detail about 'first'.  ie. the first item added to the map? the lowest Integer?   This actually looks like an X-Y problem to me.  Why are you storing the data like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to track order you will need to use a `List`. Maps are key value pairings so order is not tracked.

If you need to track order and also have multiple variables I would suggest creating an inner class and then make a list of that. Something like:

```
public class listWrapper {
    public String num;
    public Boolean foo;

    public listWrapper(String num, Boolean foo) {
        this.num = num;
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}

... then

List<listWrapper> lw = new List<listWrapper>();
lw.add(new listWrapper('24658',false));
lw.add(new listWrapper('11432',false));
lw.add(new listWrapper('121501',true));
lw.add(new listWrapper('121502',true));
```

Now you have an ordered list you can iterate over and get the value with the first true.

Please still review the resources that the commenters posted. You asked a X-Y problem  and you will find better success on this forum if you learn how to improve asking questions.